# Incoporate higher order data into Loss function

Tags: statistics, least-squares, data-analysis

Suppose we have a family of functions that governs some process of interest, $$F:=f_n(x)$$

Suppose further we have collected some data for some process, $$D:=(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), ...$$ then we have $$MSE(f_n,D) = \sum (f_n(x_k) - y_2)^2$$

We are now in a position that we can solve for the best fit $n$, using differentiation, SGD, or whatever.

However, what happens if we also collected the derivatives of $D$, $$D':=(x'_1,y'_1),(x'_2,y'_2),...$$ like we collected data on the movement of a baseball or something, which includes position measurements as well as velocity measurements. How do we formulate the MSE now to find the best fit? I would think something like $$MSE(f_n,D) = \sum (f_n(x_k) - y_2)^2 + \alpha\sum (f'_n(x'_k) - y'_2)^2 $$ But what should alpha be? Is this even correct? Should the velocity have a higher order exponent? Would it be better to use the velocity to get additional approximate values for the position and just leave the velocity data out of the MSE?

Comment: You can choose $\alpha$ to be whatever you want depending on how much you care about getting the derivative right. It depends on what the intended application is and what the best fits actually end up looking like. In a machine learning context $\alpha$ is just another hyperparameter.

Comment: I  thinking of this moreso, explicitly, setting the gradient to zero and solving algebraicly. There is insufficient data to "learn" what alpha would be best.